# detect what columns to select depending on a column value of the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table

I am trying to build a query which returns different columns of the table depending on a column of the same table. Say, a column represents a type of item.

This is my temporary solution, in which I just combine the results of multiple queries.

As you can see, I use "AS" keyword to rename the default column name.

```
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [domain_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 1
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", CAST([ip_address] AS nvarchar(15)) AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 2
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [domain_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 3
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [mail_domain]  AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 4
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", CAST([ip_address] AS nvarchar(15)) AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 5
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [domain_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 6
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [service_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 7
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to use `CASE WHEN` expression, which is well documented. So case when x = y then select this else select that etc.

Comment: It would be better if you added the solution or an example to help them.